# ¿Cómo abrir dos ventanas modales separadas? Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Tengo un proyecto en *Bootstrap*. Mi pregunta es la siguiente:

¿Cómo puedo abrir **dos ventanas modales separadas** usando dicho *Framework*?

Comment: No es muy clara tu pregunta. Deseas abrir dos popup diferentes al mismo tiempo? Si puedes ser por favor mas explicito en tu pregunta para poderte colaborar.

Comment: Si, tu pregunta es correcta pero dos ventanas o popup al mismo tiempo o sea separados que la otra ventan queda al lado. Eso quiero entender como se procesa así.

Comment: Pues te recomiendo que abras solo una con boostrap, luego a ese pop-up, le hagas un diseño personalizado, para que crees otro contenedor la lado del actual y puedas desplegar los dos contenedores, pero ya tendrías que meter html y css por tu cuenta. Por que como lo quieres hacer, bootstrap no te da las herramientas.

Comment: Por usabilidad, no habrás 2 modales y haz como sugiere Miguel Angel Gonzales Pinto, esto fácilmente puede solucionarse con un solo modal con un contenido dividido a la mitad.

Answer (score 0):

Esta pregunta se encuentra repetida en *Stack Overflow en inglés*:

- [image: How to open two modal dialogs in Twitter Bootstrap at the same time]

Acá existe un problema:

Para comprender las complejidades de los diálogos modales en el desarrollo web, deberá comprender un poco más acerca de la propiedad `z-index` y los contextos de apilamiento.

En resumen, el modal funciona al agregar dos componentes principales al *DOM*: Un fondo que ocupa toda la pantalla y un `div` que comprende su diálogo. Cada uno de ellos, se destaca del resto de la página porque se colocan en el nivel de raíz del *DOM* y se le da un valor alto para su propiedad de *índice z*.

Por ejemplo:

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in"></div>  <!-- z-index: 1030; -->
<div class="modal bootstrap-dialog">        <!-- z-index: 1040; -->
<div class="modal-dialog">                  <!-- z-index: 1050; -->
```

En el presente ejemplo, el `div` **`modal-backdrop`** será el primer modal, posteriormente se va a apilar el `div` **`modal bootstrap-dialog`** y finalmente el `div` **`modal-dialog`** (el orden es definido por la propiedad `z-Index`).

---

Solución:

Para resolver esto, debe crear su propia forma de desactivar los clics en modales de fondo (es decir, estrategias para apilar y desapilar modales), tal como la siguiente demostración:

[Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/QqqxF/223/)

Su funcionalidad es la siguiente:

1. *jsFiddle* tiene la funcionalidad al hacer clic en un diálogo, que simplemente se cierre el último cuadro de diálogo en el *DOM* y se marque el evento para que no se active nada más.
2. Si el segundo modal está activo y haces clic en él, lo único que sucederá es que el segundo modal se cerrará.

[image: Ejemplo de la demo]